# CGAL QuadTree build_with_custom_split based on node bounding box

Tags: c++, cgal, bounding-box, quadtree, octree

Following the CGAL's example in the documentation linked below:

[https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Orthtree/Orthtree_2octree_build_with_custom_split_8cpp-example.html][1]

Is it possible for one to run quadtree.bbox(n) accessor inside the custom function below?

```
struct split_if_true {
  int  flag;
  split_if_true(int flag){}
  template<class Node>
  bool operator()(const Node & n) const {
  // I need to access the node bounding box here, how can I run quadtree.bbox(n)
  return true ; 
  }
};
bool create_quad_tree(Point_vector points){
  Quadtree quadtree(points);
  int flag = 0;
  quadtree.refine(split_if_true(flag));
  return true;
};


  [1]: https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Orthtree/Orthtree_2octree_build_with_custom_split_8cpp-example.html
```